# Why does Node fs.watchFile keep test from completing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've recently integrated [config-js](https://github.com/stdarg/config-js) into a Jest test to get a configurable website url and credentials, but now my test does not fully complete.  Generally, I run `npm test` from the command line, the test executes, and the command line prompt is returned.  With config-js in the test, the testing part finishes, but the command line just hangs, and I have to ctrl+c to get back to a prompt.
I did some experimentation, and I'm pretty sure this is due to config-js's use of fs.watchFile:

```
fs.watchFile(this.pathToConfigFile, function () {
    self.loadConfig(self.pathToDefaults, self.pathToConfigFile, self.region);
});
```

When I comment these lines out, everything works fine.
I've tried using fs.watch instead, but that doesn't fix it.
Just so that it's said, I'm not actually doing any changing or hot-reloading of the config file in my tests.

In case it's helpful, here's the test:

```
const Config = require('config-js');
let myConfig = new Config('./my.config.js');
describe('config test', function () {
  it('gets the baseUrl', function() {
    expect(myConfig.get('testing.baseUrl')).toEqual('http://foo.com');
  });
});
```

And here's what the config file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  testing: {
    baseUrl: "http://foo.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [`fs.watchFile` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener):

> `persistent` `<boolean>` Indicates whether the process should continue to run as long as files are being watched. Default: **true**

Set the persistent option to false to allow your process to exit when all other operations have completed:

```
fs.watchFile(this.pathToConfigFile, {persistent: false}, function () {
    self.loadConfig(self.pathToDefaults, self.pathToConfigFile, self.region);
})
```